# How to include a XAML into another XAML in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I need to include a common XAML in several different XAML layout files.

I do not want to hard code the repeated XAML part in those other XAML files.

How to do the include ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you turn the shared code into a [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)?

ALternatively you could use [templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to generate the XAML which contains the shared code.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that UserControl is suitable.